# php xml loop not working properly.

Tags: php, xml, html

i'm new on stackoverflow but i follow this site from long time. I'm working on a simply web application that will be a catalogue for some music tracks that will be added by users after a registration.
I've started the project from an html5 template who i found online and now i'm mixing it with all the features i want to add (like the registration and tracks upload). I've added a simply registration system and the ability to write the tracks information on a file xml. I used in the old version of the project a mysql database to store all the data, but due to some problems i decided to use xml to manage the tracks information. 
Now the problem is to fetch all the data from the xml file and to put them into the html tags that will be used to show the title, year and the artist name, the script i'm using is not working properly and return to me only the first track informations that are stored into the xml file, the rest of the nodes are not displayed..

the code i'm using for loading the xml file and display it is the following:

```
 <?php
 $xml=simplexml_load_file("tracks.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
 foreach ($xml->children() as $tracks):
 for($i = 0; $i < 0; $i++){
    $title=$tracks->title[$i];
    $artist=$tracks->artist[$i];
    $relyear=$tracks->year[$i];
 }
 ?>
```

The html code that will show the information instead is this:

```
 <ul class="grid">
 <li class="grid__item">
 <a class="grid__link" href="#album-1" data-    playlist-1="" data-playlist-2=""> 
 <div class="img-wrap img-wrap--grid">
 <svg class="lp lp--grid">
 <use xlink:href="#icon-lp-mini"></use>
 </svg>
 <img class="img img--grid" src="img/album10.jpg" alt="album1" />
 </div>
 <span class="year">1999</span>
 <h2 class="artist"><?php echo $artist ?></h2>
 <h3 class="title"><?php echo $title ?></h3>
 </a>
 </li>
 </ul>
```

This part of the code is duplicated for 12 times because the masonry grid show 12 items at times. Any idea on how i can show different informations for every different tracks in the grid?

Comment: Can we get a sample XML paste?

Comment: `for($i = 0; $i < 0; $i++)` this loop won't be entered, because when you start with `$i = 0` and check for `$i < 0` it will evaluate to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use DOMDocument to get your data. See this working example using your XML:
https://3v4l.org/RLK1U

Comment: ok, i will try with the code you provided. I have just one question, if i remove the " echo $artist.', '.$title.', '.$year."\n"; " at the end of the script and i use the <?php echo $title ?> or <?php echo $artist?> .. it will work or i will have a problem? I need to print the information into the html..

Comment: <?= $rows; ?> seems not work if i place it in the <h3> that hold the info about title and artist. I will give another try to the code you provided this night.
If you want to see the html full template code where i started from, here is the link: 
https://tympanus.net/Development/RecordPlayer/
As you can see, it's a nice grid, i hope to find a solution to maintain this style and to display xml infos..

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the for loop, but the script continue to give me only the same result for title, artist name and year.

As requested from delboy1978uk, here use the xml file that i'm using to develop the app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<releases>
<track>
<artist>salva</artist>
<title>nome</title>
<year>2015</year>
<label>maxa</label>
</track>
<track>
<artist>another test</artist>
<title>tracks</title>
<year>2022</year>
<label>buru</label>
</track>
<track>
<artist>re</artist>
<title>de</title>
<year>?</year>
<label>df</label>
</track>
<track>
<artist>yu</artist>
<title>tube</title>
<year>5</year>
<label>fy</label>
</track>
</releases>
```

The file is updated by a php script that add new data using the existing tag scheme, so if i use the projected form to add a new track, it will appear into the file as a new node.

Answer (score -1):

You have for loop inside your foreach loop which makes no sense.
Also your for loop is incorrect-

```
for($i = 0; $i < 0; $i++) {
```

$i starts with 0. So it will never get passed this zero.

Comment: You've downvoted my answer but i am not the first one to notice this typo.